# React-Native Testing Library/Jest:Cannot read property 'TouchableOpacity'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

im doing some testing using jest and react-native testing, the problem is the TouchableOpacity is not recognized and cause errors

Card.test.js

```
import Card from "../Card"
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


const onePost = { title: "random photo", username: "martin", score: "1233", comments: "4322", creationDate: "6 hours ago",  url: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61FlX89mYGL." }

jest.mock('react-native-gesture-handler', () => {
    dropGestureHandler: jest.fn()
})
afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();

})

test('render title of the post correctly', () => {   
    const component = render(<Card {...onePost} />);
    expect(component.getByText(onePost.title)).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Card.js

```
 

    import React from "react";
    import { Text, Image, View, StyleSheet, Linking,Pressable } from "react-native";
    import timeDifference from "../lib/timeDifference";
    import { Touchable } from 'react-native-web';
    import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    
    export default function Card({ title, username, score, comments, creationDate, image, url }) {
        //we render the data from props
        return (
           
             <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => { Linking.openURL('https://www.reddit.com' + url) }}
                            style={styles.card}  >
                    <View  style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                        <View style={styles.cardImage}>
                            <Image
                                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                                source={{ uri: image }}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, marginHorizontal: 12 }}>
                            <Text style={styles.cardLocation}>{timeDifference(creationDate)} ago</Text>
                            <Text 
                                style={styles.cardTitle}>{title}</Text>
                        
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
            
        );
    }
```

When i run the tests it says "Cannot read property 'TouchableOpacity' of undefined", when i change the TouchableOpacity for a View it runs ok

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference, but could the `<>` about the tag be causing the problem

Comment: wait.... are blank tags a thing now?  I could be wrong about my above comment

Comment: @DJBurb A thing now? Or been a thing for a few years.  [Fragment short-syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax)

Comment: @DrewReese I haven't used React in a few years.  Rarely used `<Fragment>` on top of that

Comment: @DJBurb Introduced in React 16 ([16.2.0 actually](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html)) back in Nov 2017.

Comment: @DJBurb i dont think the Fragment is doing anything

Comment: @MartinCavanagh yeah, I was not familiar with the short syntax for Fragment and thought it was a typo

Comment: Try using TouchableOpacity as imported from react-native instead of gesture handler

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the issue you're experiencing with Jest and React Native Testing Library lies in the way you're importing `TouchableOpacity`. Currently, you are importing it from `'react-native-gesture-handler'`, but you should be importing it directly from `'react-native'`.

In your `Card.js`, change the import statement for `TouchableOpacity` to look like this:

**Before**

```
 import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

**After**

```js
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
```

This ensures that you are using the `TouchableOpacity` component provided by React Native, which is more appropriate for use in your tests with Jest and React Native Testing Library. The `'react-native-gesture-handler'` library is generally used for handling more complex gestures and might not be compatible in the same way with your testing environment.